# How to change .pfx file or its contents when migrating to subdomain

Tags: subdomain, migrate, pfx

I have moved the website to a sub-domain. Now, when I do the `webpay` transactions from this sub-domain, it fails.

I think I might have to generate new certificate files for the changed domain or can I make edits to the existing `pfx` file and change `url`??